# Time delayed text animation with macOS Keynote

Tags: macos, ios, mac, keynote

I want to achieve a very common animation with macOS keynote as described bellow:

A phrase consists of few words to appear on the screen word by word.
The first word appears first, starting from a little bellow of its original position and then moves to its original position.
Then after a short delay, the 2nd word follows the same kind of animation.
Then after a short delay the 3rd word, and so on.

For a demo, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUcxoScgWS4&t=92s) has a similar animation. The phrase `Who is eligible for a handle?` animates there like what I have described above. The link URL was captured at (almost) the correct time of the animation.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would it help to have several text elements animated individually?

Comment: I tried almost every built in effects, but none of them helped to achieve this.

Comment: I get that, but can‘t you animate each word separately to achieve a similar effect?

Comment: Yes, but it is a daunting task specially if I need to animate multiple phrases. I am looking for a better & simpler reusable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you want, but this seems like a simple application of the "Fade and Move" build-in animation:

[image: screenshot of Keynote fade and move animation]

I've set it to a slight delay between steps (2s) moved from bottom to top, and you want to animate each word, rather than the default "by object" (which is the whole phrase).

You can control the distance you want and the direction (here bottom to top).

[image: animated fade "who is eligible for a handle"]